# How to find the value of $x$ that $T_{\infty} f(x)$ convert to $f(x)$?

Tags: calculus, integration, sequences-and-series, limits, taylor-expansion

I am not sure whether I am right about the general solution to these questions.

I think Taylor series convert to the original function only when $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}R_{n}f(x) = 0$

However, using Lagrange remainder theorem only enables me to estimate the remainder. How can I calculate the range of $x$ making the Taylor series convert to the function?

For example, for which real numbers x does the Taylor series of $f(x) = \frac {1} {2-5x}$ converge to $f(x)$?

My approach is:

First, we know $$T_{n}\frac {1}{1-t} = 1 + x +x^2 +\cdots + x^n$$

So using substitution and product operation, we got
$$T_{n}\frac {1}{2-5x} = \frac {1}{2} + \frac {5}{4}x +\frac {25x^2}{8} +\cdots + \frac {(5x)^n}{2^{n+1}}$$

Then I have no ideas how to analyze the remainder term $R_n\frac {1}{2-5x}$

Any suggestions?

Comment: Do you know when the [geometrical series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series) $\frac{1}{1-x} = 1+x+x^2+\ldots$ converge? If so then you should be able to deduce when $\frac{1}{2-5x} = \frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{1-(5x/2)} = \frac{1}{2} + \frac{5x}{4} + \ldots$ converge.

Comment: @Winther Yes, I know that. I am confused about the statements that "the series converge" and " "the Taylor series converge to the function $f(x)$". Are they the same?

Comment: Here yes. The geometrical series $1+ x+ x^2+ \ldots$ converge to $\frac{1}{1-x}$ for all $|x|<1$ and you have shown that the Taylor series of $\frac{1}{2-5x}$ is a geometrical series. Just determine where it converges and you have your answer.

Comment: @Winther Thank you so much! So normally when I get those questions, can I interpret it as asking me "where does the series converge"?

Comment: My comment was for this specific series. It's not always the case in general. Consider [for example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series#Approximation_and_convergence) the Taylor series of $f(x) = e^{-\frac{1}{x^2}}$ if $x\not= 0$ with $f(0) = 0$. This function has Taylor series (about $x=0$) equal to $T_n f(x) = 0$ which converges but the limit ($=0$) is not equal to $f(x)$.

Comment: @Winther I see, thank you Winther! Have a day.